# How to write average constraints in CPLEX OPL?

Tags: cplex, opl

I have several questions regarding modelling constraints. I guess it should be really simple, but I am unable to figure it out. First, let me sketch the situation: I would like to optimize a multi-dimensional knapsack problem. However, I get some difficulties with two constraint.

I am first reading an Excel sheet with the following columns:

```
{string} Items = …;
tuple Item {
int weight;
int classification_1;
int classification_2;
…}

dvar int a[Items] in 0..1;
```

classification_1 and classification_2 are two separate classifications of the objects, you can imagine that for example classification_1 contains an integer that represents a color, while classification_2 has another property (for example the shape, where a number represents a certain shape).
To clarify things even more, you can imagine an object as follows:

```
Ball_object; 23; 1; 2; …
```

Where Ball_object is the name, 23 is the weight, 1 the color blue and 2 a circle shape, the other properties are not immediately relevant for my question.
Now suppose I have the following constraint:
1.  For all items, their weights should be less than 10% of the total weight of the selected items.

I have tried the following:

```
Subjected to {
    Forall ( i_1 in Items )
    ctItemRatio:
    (Item[i_1].weight * a[i_1]) / (sum (I in Items) (Item[i].weight * a[i])) <= 0.1;
}
```

But this does not appear to work, as my CPLEX studio cannot extract expression. But I am a bit confused what I actually did wrong with this constraint. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

2. For every shape, the total weights of a given shape should not exceed 15% of the total weight.

I have actually not a really clue how to do this, since I cannot just iterate through classification_2 right? How can I model it such that I can use a forall through classification_2? (I would love to find a OPL solution rather than just naming all the shapes by hand.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For constraint 1, if you multiply both sides by `sum (I in Items) (Item[i].weight * a[i])` (i.e., remove it from the LHS and put it on the RHS), does it work?

Comment: For constraint 2, I assume you mean the total weights of the items *selected* of a given shape should not exceed 15% of the total weight of the *selected* items? Couldn't you first build a list of the unique values of classification_2, and then loop through those values, building the constraint for each?

Comment: For constraint 2, the total weights of the items selected of a given shape should not exceed 15%.

Comment: 15% of what? The total weight of all items? All items of that shape? All selected items?

Comment: 15% of the weight of all the selected items.

Comment: OK that's what I thought. Does my suggestion (build a list of unique values, loop through those, build a list for each) make sense, or am I missing something?

Comment: As for your first suggestion, it remarkably worked! But I have no idea why the division does not work, while the multiplication does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193909/discussion-between-larrysnyder610-and-snowflake).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For constraint #1, the way you wrote it is nonlinear. If you just multiply both sides by `sum (I in Items) (Item[i].weight * a[i])`, it becomes linear and CPLEX should be happy:

```
Item[i_1].weight * a[i_1] <= 0.1 * (sum (I in Items) (Item[i].weight * a[i]));
```

For constraint #2, I would suggest building a list of unique values of classification_2 (before you call the OPL code), and then loop through those values, building a constraint for each. I'm not familiar with the syntax of OPL, but presumably you can add a condition within the sum; something like:

```
sum (i in Items : classification_2[i] == <some value>)
```